# VueJS - Best practises for performance : one individual modal or storing a modal in component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm making some updates to one of my VueJS apps, and there are a few different ways I could go about it. I wanted to know what the best practice was in terms of performance, or if there isn't much of a difference at all.

Essentially I have a couple of different pages, each of these pages present results in a table. I'm using Boostrap to manage the tables. What I want to do is have a button at the far end of the table that opens a modal where you can see detailed results for that specific line entry in the table.

Now because there are tables on different pages and I want the same behaviour, I want to have the modal / button in their own component, that way I can just copy-paste the component from one page to the next and have the exact same behaviour.

My question is this, is there a difference between :

- Having the modal on the page itself, and having all the logic in the page itself
- Having a component containing the modal and the logic, and repeating that component 1000s of times in the different tables

Is there any performance difference between having the modal repeated 1000 times in the table versus having only one modal in the page? My understanding is that the modal wouldn't be loaded until you click the button anyway, so would it have an impact on performance?

Comment: Are you using Vuex and is all of the data for the modal available in the store?

Comment: The data is pulled from an API when the users perform a query on the page. @maxshuty

Comment: Do you have a store though?

Comment: @maxshuty I do for user authentication / basic data, yes, why? Does that have an impact on modals / components / tables?